# Как получить путь к %appdata%

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, c++17

В QT есть функция:

```
QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation)
```

Однако, на выходе получаем:

```
C:/Users/BBCCA/AppData/Roaming/%APPNAME%
```

А мне нужно:

```
C:/Users/BBCCA/AppData/Roaming
```

Как это можно грамотно сделать?

Comment: Добавь /.. / к пути

Comment: @eri - вы сами поняли, что написали?

Comment: [SHGetKnownFolderPath](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath)

Comment: @user7860670 это платформенно зависимая функция

Comment: Ну правильно, платформенно зависимая функция для получения платформенно зависимого пути.

Comment: @user7860670 я не просто так указал qt. мне нужен путь аналогичный %appdata%, НО! в qt есть кроссплатформенное получение путей QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation). Ваш же способ потом в убунту работать не будет

Comment: в убунте отсутствует %appdata%.

Comment: @user7860670 гуглите: QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation

Comment: Эта функция на убунте не ищет %appdata%, так как его там в принципе нет, а выбирает какой-нибудь путь, доступный для записи и хранения того, что на windows обычно сохраняется в %appdata%.

Comment: @user7860670 не какой-то, а путь для хранения данных приложений.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Пока что из вариантов нашел подобные костыли:

```
QCoreApplication::setApplicationName("");
const QString appDataPath = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation) + QDir::separator() + "commands.slimrg";
QCoreApplication::setApplicationName(%APPNAME%);
```

Где - `%APPNAME%` - название вашего приложения

Comment: А не проще appname поменять на нужное?

Comment: @eri мне нужен путь без appname